# Oracle SQL - Removing leading patterned substring

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a data field in an Oracle 12cR1 database.  The field is a product descriptor, and the start of the field contains the product ID.  It is then followed by the product name.  I need to strip off the Product ID.  The product ID can be in one of 2 formats... The data typically looks like one of the following:

- 0P3H - Opus NEM
- 0P22 - 40021 - Order Capture Self Service

Note that there are some cases where the '-' character is part of the product name, such as

- 0C34 - HR - Promotions Module

As far as I can tell, I need to delete the following WHEN IT IS AT THE START OF THE STRING...

- 4 characters then space then dash then space
- 4 characters then space then dash then space 5 characters space dash
  space

How would I write Oracle SQL to read a field and REMOVE these 2 different substrings?

Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, `case` might be the simplest:

```
select (case when field like '____ - _____ -%' then substr(field, 15)
             else substr(field, 7)
        end)
```

Comment: This worked, although I had to add the '%' , like this...select (case when field like '____ - _____ -%' then substr(field, 15)
             else substr(field, 7)

Answer (score 0):

Substring in reverse to the first '-' and then substr to the end of the string from that starting position.

```
select TRIM(substr('0P3H - Opus NEM', instr('0P3H - Opus NEM', '-', -1, 1) + 1)) from dual

select TRIM(substr('0P22 - 40021 - Order Capture Self Service', instr('0P22 - 40021 - Order Capture Self Service', '-', -1, 1) + 1)) from dual
```

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that you mentioned that in some cases '-' can be part of the name. In that case, the method I described will not work.